# Angular strict strictPropertyInitialization - where to init member?

Tags: angular, typescript

During the initialization of a component I want to retrieve some user information.
Now, with the Angular strict mode, I'm not sure where to load this data?

I can think of 3 options. But which is the correct one? Or is there another possibility?

#1 in this option the service method will be called directly on initialization of the userInfo.

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  public userInfo$: Observable<LoggedInUser> = this.sessionService.getUserInformation();

  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

#2 In my opinion it will be better to source this into the constructor like so:

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  public isMobileMenuCollapsed = true;
  public userInfo$: Observable<LoggedInUser>;

  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {
    this.userInfo$ = this.sessionService.getUserInformation();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

#3 in the ngOnInit-method instead of the constructor. But for this solution I need the Definite Assignment Assertion as well:

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  public isMobileMenuCollapsed = true;
  public userInfo$!: Observable<LoggedInUser>;

  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userInfo$ = this.sessionService.getUserInformation();
}
```

}

Which of this possibilties should I use in my code?

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR use option #1.

**Which one is correct?**

Are you using `userInfo$` only in your HTML template?
Then all of the three options should work in theory.

**Why?**

Because template code runs after `ngOnInit`, so `userInfo$` should have been initialized by then in all three options.

**Which one is better?**

#1 and #2 is essentially same, in both cases, `userInfo$` is getting initialized in constructor. I prefer #1 as it removes redundancy in code.

#3 is slightly different as the initialization is not happening in constructor. So this may introduce some subtle bugs if you use `userInfo$` inside the component (for example, in `ngOnChanges` which gets called before `ngOnInit`).

Comment: great answer. Are there any situations where #1 and #2 doesn't work? For example in complex situations, where some variables initialized after the constructor call? I can imagine of @ViewChilds, which can only be used safely in ngOnInit or after. Would be #3 the correct way for such a situation?

Comment: And yes, in this case userInfo$ will only be used in the html template

Comment: Yes, exactly right. For those cases where the value is not available in constructor, you have to initialize when the value is available (`ngOnInit`, `ngAfterViewInit`, `ngAfterContentInit`).

Even in those cases, another alternative is to define a `Subject`, and then define the `userInfo$` observable based on the Subject.

Answer (score 2):

What is you real problem? I guess it is about a mismatch of types in your template while using the async pipe?

You need to know the async pipe may return `null` the mismatch is not with you observable but with the result of the pipe.

How to fix it?

Well, introduce a *ngIf on the element or on an element on higher level and use the result. Because of the *ngIf the data type cannot contain `null` anymore

`<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">`

Comment: I don't have any problems. My async pipes work as expected (as you mentioned in your last sentence). My question was only, which is the correct way for doing it, because in the official angular documentation / tutorial, it isn't described properly imo.